# Cannot show images from parse.com in listview

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, bitmap, android-image

I am trying to retrieve images that I have saved on Parse.com. There are no errors but the images are not showing up. I am using a custom adapter.

This is the activity. I tried running the debugger but could not find any issue there.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_activty);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    fileArrayList =  new ArrayList<ParseFile>();

    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Images");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                for (ParseObject obj : list) {
                    ParseFile i = obj.getParseFile("Image");
                    fileArrayList.add(i);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving images: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    listviewAdapter = new ListviewAdapter(ImageActivty.this, fileArrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);


}
```

This is my adapter.

```
public class ListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final static String TAG = ListviewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private List<ParseFile> sellers;
int layout;

public ListviewAdapter(Context activity, List<ParseFile> sellers) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.sellers = sellers;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public  class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    FrameLayout rl;
    TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v =view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }


    ParseFile s = sellers.get(position);
    byte[] bitmapdata = new byte[0];
    try {
        bitmapdata = s.getData();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("ListAdapter","Error here.");
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata.length);

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Log.d("CustomAdapter.class", "CustomAdapter");
    return v;
 }
}
```

A friend of mine helped me with conversion of the parsefile to bitmap in the adapter. I suspect that the implementation is wrong. If yes, how do I convert a ParseFile to bitmap. Is there any other way to retrieve and set images to imageview in a list from Parse.com?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this code :

```
listviewAdapter = new ListviewAdapter(ImageActivty.this, fileArrayList);
lv.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);
```

is run before this one

```
 if (e == null) {
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (ParseObject obj : list) {
                ParseFile i = obj.getParseFile("Image");
                fileArrayList.add(i);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving images: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

in most cases, because findInBackground is asynchronous. Then, you have to notify your adapter that its data set has changed, once your pictures have been loaded :

```
 listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Do it here :

```
   if (e == null) {
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (ParseObject obj : list) {
                ParseFile i = obj.getParseFile("Image");
                fileArrayList.add(i);
            }
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving   images: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

You could also instanciate and set the listAdapter at this moment.

Comment: I tried instaciating it inside the asynchronous findInBackground method. It does not work. In fact, I get a null pointer exception for setting the adapter. Even if I just use notifyDataSetChanged, all I get is a blank screen.

Comment: Are you sure  your  images are retrieved ?

Comment: Yes. I checked the debugger. Each object retreived from Parse.com includes the corresponding image. The problem can be either with the declaration of the adapter or the conversion of images from Parsefile to byte[]. I have done this vefore using ParseImageview but I am not sure how to acueve this without it. This application requires that I dont use ParseImageView.

Comment: Anyway, you have to notify the adapter. You may also try tour conversion outside of tour adapter, on a simple ImageView first.

Comment: Furthermore, when you use getParseFile(), you do not get the data of your image. You have to call getDataInBackground on it. You may also use Picasso lib.

Comment: I did not take that into consideration. Thanks a lot. But the inages are still not showing up. I have tried a kot fo things. As I am fairly new to this domain, it is hard for me to find what exactly I may be doig wrong. Can I share the link to my github repo here? Is it okay?

Comment: I found your  repo. The  problem is also that getdatainbackground is asynchronous too... So tour notify is called  before the loading. Try putting instead the  getDataInBackground in the  adapter or use Picasso.

Comment: I did try it. Trying to run the debugger again, I found that for some reason the imagelist.size( ) returns 0 after the findInBackground method. The debugger does not work for the getInBackground()  method.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I figured it out on my own. I had to move the ParseQuery and the adapter to a Async task. That way I was able to manipulate the adapter  only when the the background task was completed. The concepts given by Thibault came in very handy. Plus I used the universal image loader to perform the setting of the images. I tried with picasso as well and it worked as well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_activty);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ImageActivty.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Images loading");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.getProgress();
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<ParseImage>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Images");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                country.pinInBackground();
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseImage parseImage = new ParseImage();
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("Image");
                String objectID = country.getObjectId();
                parseImage.setImage(image);
                parseImage.setObjectID(objectID);
                worldpopulationlist.add(parseImage);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListviewAdapter(ImageActivty.this,
                worldpopulationlist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```